# Connection to Openshift origin using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, openshift-origin

I want to connect to my Openshift Origin instance, but via Eclipse. I installed Codeready Studio in Eclipse and logged in the Redhat Openshift extention for Eclipse. However, when I want to set up server adapters and start port forwarding, it shows the following error :

> OpenShiftBinaryCapability process exited: error: specifying a root certificates file with the insecure flag is not allowed

*The location for OC is C:\CLI*

Answer (score -1):

Try to change your ~/.kube/config specifies a cluster with insecure-skip-tls-verify: true,
Use following command to set --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true C:\Users\username.kube folder

**kubectl config set-cluster clustername --server=https://Openshift IP:8443 --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true**

"insecure-skip-tls-verify" allows interaction with an HTTPS server bypassing the server certificate checks; however, note that it is not secure. If you try to oc
login to a HTTPS server that does not provide a valid certificate, and this or the --certificate-authority flags were not provided

This worked for me.